# Custom Tableview Cell Disappears when reloading table with a new picture

Tags: swift, firebase, imageview, tableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a very strange issue occurring that I have not seen before while developing.  It makes it very difficult to troubleshoot due to the fact the app is not crashing and there is no erroneous debug output in the console window.

I have an edit user profile ViewController.  On this page it displays the users first and last name, e-mail and phone number, along with a picture.  This is all being pulled from Firebase and is working fine.  The "picture" you see is an actual JPG that is "uploaded" when someone creates an account, this way the photo URL is stored in their database and I can retrieve it to display a photo.  In theory, when "editing" a profile, the user would see a real pic in there, and "change" it with the one they are taking or upload.

The issue I am having is that when I finish selecting a picture from the gallery or take one from the camera, it correctly dismisses the camera or gallery, but the "tableviewcell" dissapears, and I do not see the picture or the text. Oddly enough, the text fields remain that are not part of the table.  The intent is to have the pic that is "taken" temporarily appear in the UIImage view (which lives in the tableviewcell) and then when the user hits "save", it will upload to FireBase (that part I know how to do).  That VC then gets dismissed and the data on in ProfileVC is reloaded from FireBase with the new pic.

I have the firebase part down as well as I correctly (I think) coded the image picker, but there has to be something I am missing as to why the temporary image is not displaying.

As an additional troubleshooting step I commented out the line: **self.editProfileTable.reloadData()** under the function **imagePickerContoller** in the **EditProfileVC.swift** file.  When I did that, after hitting "chose Photo" that view dismisses and it goes right back to the **Before Update Picture** picture below.  It has to be something with the table, but I am just not seeing it.

I have included all relevant code below.

***EditProfileVC.swift***

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class EditProfileVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, Alertable, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var delegate : ImagePickerDelegate?
    var tempImage : UIImage?
    var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController?

    @IBOutlet var editProfileTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var editEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var editMobileTextField: UITextField!

    var editProfileInfo = [EditProfileModel]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return editProfileInfo.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "editprofilecell", for: indexPath) as! EditProfileTableViewCell

        let editprofile: EditProfileModel

        editprofile = editProfileInfo[indexPath.row]

        cell.firstNameLabel.text = editprofile.firstname
        cell.lastNameLabel.text = editprofile.lastname
        cell.emailLabel.text = editprofile.email
        cell.mobileLabel.text = editprofile.mobile


        cell.tapButton = {(user) in
            self.pickImage()
        }


        if tempImage == nil {
        DataService.instance.REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                self.editProfileInfo.removeAll()
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if snap.key == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        let imageUrl = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "userPhoto").value
                        //  print(imageUrl)
                        let storage = Storage.storage()
                        let ref = storage.reference(forURL: imageUrl as! String)
                        ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                            if error != nil {
                                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                            } else {

                                cell.updateProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

        delegate?.pickImage()

        cell.updateProfileImage.image = tempImage

        return cell

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        editEmailTextField.delegate = self
        editMobileTextField.delegate = self

        view.bindtoKeyboard()

       imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleScreenTap(sender:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        DataService.instance.REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                self.editProfileInfo.removeAll()
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if snap.key == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        let profileObject = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let profileFirstName = profileObject?["first_name"]
                        let profileLastName = profileObject?["last_name"]
                        let profileMobile = profileObject?["mobile_number"]
                        let profileEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email

                        let editprofile = EditProfileModel(firstname: profileFirstName as! String?, lastname: profileLastName as! String?, email: profileEmail , mobile: profileMobile as! String?)

                        self.editProfileInfo.append(editprofile)
                    }

                    self.editProfileTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })

             delegate?.pickImage()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    @objc func handleScreenTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func pickImage() {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            self.openCamera()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            self.openGallery()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

//        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
//        imagePicker.delegate = self
//        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
//        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
//        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func openCamera()
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func openGallery()
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have perission to access gallery.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            tempImage = pickedImage
            self.editProfileTable.reloadData()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // imageViewPic.image = pickedImage
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated:  true, completion: nil)
    }
```

***EditProfileModel.swift***

```
class EditProfileModel {

    var firstname: String?
    var lastname: String?
    var email: String?
    var mobile: String?

    init(firstname: String?, lastname: String?, email: String?, mobile: String?){
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.email = email
        self.mobile = mobile
    }
}
```

***EditProfileTableViewCell.swift***

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var delegate : ImagePickerDelegate?

class EditProfileTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var updateProfileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var mobileLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func btdDetailsClick(_ sender: Any) {
        tapButton?(self)
        delegate?.pickImage()
    }
    var tapButton: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?


}
```

***ImagePicker.swift***

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol ImagePickerDelegate {

    func pickImage()

}
```

[Before Update Picture button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESIdS.png)

[After Update Image button pressed and all code above is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCerl.png)